# Find a word in a File and print the line that contains it in java

Tags: java

Using command line, I am supposed to enter a file name that contains text and search for a specific word.

> foobar file.txt

I started writing the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Find {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String word = args[0];
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File (args[1]) );
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String x = input.nextLine();    
        }
    }
}
```

My program is supposed to find word and then print the whole line that contains it.
Please be specific since I am new to java.

Comment: And what's the problem really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already reading in each line of the file, so using the `String.contains()` method will be your best solution

```
if (x.contains(word) ...
```

The `contains()` method simply returns `true` if the given `String` contains the character sequence (or String) you pass to it.

**Note:** This check *is* case sensitive, so if you want to check if the word exists with any mix of capitalization, just convert the strings to the same case first:

```
if (x.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) ...
```

---

So now here is a complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String word = args[0];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));

    // Let's loop through each line of the file
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();

        // Now, check if this line contains our keyword. If it does, print the line
        if (line.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firest you have to open file and then read it line by line and check that word is in that line on not. see the code below.

```
class Find {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
          String word = args[0]; // the word you want to find
          try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foobar.txt"))) { // open file foobar.txt
          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //read file line by line in a loop
             if(line.contains(word)) { // check if line contain that word then prints the line
                  System.out.println(line);
              } 
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to the answer